# Right margin of a cventry

Tags: margins, moderncv

I try to adjust the right margin of a cventry for the ModernCV template to match with the overall right margin but it is always broader (see screenshot). I tried geometry package and minipage but both have not solved the problem.

Here is example code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv} 
\moderncvstyle{banking} 
\moderncvcolor{black} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{enumitem} 
\usepackage[official]{eurosym}


\name{David}{Doe}
\usepackage[scale=0.9]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\section{Employment}
\begin{itemize}
\item{
\cventry{11/2019 - current}{Hello}{Hello}{Hello}{}{\vspace{0pt}
\begin{itemize}[label=$\bullet$] 
\item{XXX}
\end{itemize}}
}

\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is that you are using the `\cventry` within an `itemize` environment.

The command is by itself already optimised to use the entire textwidth and being an item shifts the entire line to the right.

This should work for you:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv} 
\moderncvstyle{banking} 
\moderncvcolor{black} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{enumitem} 
\usepackage[official]{eurosym}
  
\name{David}{Doe}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}
\begin{document}
    \section{Employment}
        \cventry{11/2019 - current}{Hello}{Hello}{Hello}{}{\vspace{0pt}
            \begin{itemize}[label=$\bullet$] 
                \item{XXX}
            \end{itemize}}
\end{document}
```

I replaced `scale` for a proper `margin` option, but that is not related to your issue, more to a way of layouting that is easier to understand.

Comment: Thank you! You are just awesome! I was really blind not seeing this.